# Units in a quotient ring: $R=\Bbb F_3[x]/\langle x^2-1\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

Let $f=x^2 - 1 \in \mathbb{F}_3[x]$, $R=\mathbb{F}_3[x] / \langle f \rangle$ and $\alpha = x + \langle f \rangle$. I am trying to show that $\alpha$, $-\alpha$, $1$ and $-1$ are units in $R$. Clearly $1$ is a unit since $1 \cdot 1 = 1$. Likewise, $-1$ is its own inverse. But I am unsure how to find an inverse for $\alpha$ and $-\alpha$.

I am also unsure how to perform arithmetic in $R$. For example, if we let $\beta = x^2 - 1 + \langle f \rangle$ what is $\alpha \cdot \beta$? Can I do usual multiplication here? Then how does the modulus come into play?

Is there a general approach for finding $\alpha$'s inverse? Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following, $\hat a$ will denote the class of $a \in \Bbb F _3$ modulo the ideal $\langle f \rangle$.

Well, it's pretty straightforward: since $f = x^2 - 1$ and $\hat f = \hat 0$ in $R$ (and the projection from $\Bbb F _3$ to $R$ is a morphism), this means that $\hat 0 = \hat x ^2 - \hat 1$, or equivalently $\hat x ^2 = \hat 1$, which shows that $\hat x$ is invertible in $R$ and its inverse is $\hat x$ itself. This means that $\hat \alpha = \hat x + \hat f = \hat x$ is invertible and its inverse is $\hat \alpha$. Similarly, given that $(-1)^2 = 1$, you have that the inverse of $-\hat \alpha$ is itself, again.

Answer (score 1):

There is a general apporach. Usually, one likes to compute representatives. If you want to compute a representative of $\alpha \beta$, you need to compute $\alpha \beta\ mod\ f$ in $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$.

To find the inverse of $\alpha$, you need to compute the gcd of $\alpha$ and $f$ in $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$. The algorithm will compute the Bezout-coefficients, s.t. $ a\alpha + b f = gcd(\alpha, f)$. If the gcd is a unit, $a$ is your inverse. If not, there is no inverse.